# Serving Scala.js assets

Tags: scala, sbt, asset-pipeline, scala.js, finch

I've started new project with [Finch](https://github.com/finagle/finch) and [Scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org/), where backend and frontend need to share some code.

And I'm concerned about a good way to serve JS produced by `fastOptJS` by Finch. Currently, I'm using custom SBT task which copies files from `js/target/scala-2.11/*.js` to `jvm/src/main/resources`. But I wondering if there's a better way to do it.

I saw awesome [SPA tutorial](https://github.com/ochrons/scalajs-spa-tutorial), which uses sbt-play-scalajs plugin, but It seems applicable only for Play.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach which I've used successfully involves 3 sbt projects and an additional folder at the root for static content:

```
.
├── build.sbt
├── client
├── server
├── shared
└── static
```

In the `build.sbt`, you would then use something like the following:

```
lazy val sharedSettings = Seq(
  // File changes in `/static` should never trigger new compilation
  watchSources := watchSources.value.filterNot(_.getPath.contains("static")))

lazy val server = project
  .settings(sharedSettings: _*)
  // Adds `/static` to the server resources
  .settings(unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / ".." / "static")

lazy val client = project
  .enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
  .settings(sharedSettings: _*)
  // Changes Scala.js target folder to "/static/content/target"
  .settings(Seq(fullOptJS, fastOptJS, packageJSDependencies, packageScalaJSLauncher, packageMinifiedJSDependencies)
    .map(task => crossTarget in (Compile, task) := file("static/content/target")))
```

All you assets can be accessed as standard resources, then will also get packaged into your fat jar if you use something like `sbt-assembly`.

Comment: [Here is](https://github.com/OlivierBlanvillain/full-stack-scala/blob/master/build.sbt) a complete build example which deals with other stuff such as live reloading the server with `sbt revolver` and  uniformisation of `fastOptJS`/`fullOptJS`.

Comment: Hey, thank you! Looks like that is what I was looking for.